# Datatables 1.10 Responsive search expand to show child rows

Tags: search, children, responsive, datatables-1.10, expandable

I'm using Datatables 1.10 with the Responsive extension with column controlled child rows.
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html

How can I configure the search so that child rows which match are expanded/visible?

For example, on this page if I search for "5407" the table is filtered to show the parent row, but the match is only found in the child row. How can I get the search result to expand to show the matching child row?

https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/Ldgutob0/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
      details: {
        type: 'column'
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      className: 'control',
      orderable: false,
      targets: 0
    }],
    order: [1, 'asc']
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically open all child rows after a search in a `search.dt` handler :

```js
$('#example').on('search.dt', function() {
  table
   .rows({ filter: "applied" })
   .every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
     $('td:first-child', this.node()).trigger('click.dtr');
   })
})
```

Updated fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/Ldgutob0/2/** Each time a filter / search is processed all *visible* rows will get its child row opened. I noticed the `.dtr` suffix by investigating the code, it is just a namespace I believe is abbreviation of "dataTables responsive", good to know if there is custom click handlers you not want to accidently get involved by a `trigger()`.

This will of course open any child row regardless the filtered value is actually present in hidden or visible columns.

Comment: Hi David!  Thank you very much for you help.   I think the click is being triggered with each keystroke.  So, if I take the example "5407"... "5" opens the child rows, "54" closes them, "540" opens them and "5407" closes them.   Is it possible to have the click triggered fired once if the search filter is not blank (expanding the child rows), and again when it is reset to blank (collapsing the child rows)?

Comment: Hi again @davidkonrad.  I've done a bit of research and found a way to implement a searchWait.  Now the click.dtr is only activated after an interval of 5 seconds.  Here is my new fiddle:  
https://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/wjx9tLLL/

However, I'm struggling to find a way to cal the click.dtr again on when the search field is cleared.  I'm thinking that something like this should work, but can't manage to figure out how to implement it.  

$('input[type="search"]').val('').keyup()

Comment: @lbriquet, did the answer help you out or should I delete it ...?